# jquery does not focus on form field

Tags: jquery

Why does the following page not work with the form tags included (as below), but does when they are removed? (new to jquery, obviously...)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
              $('#inputid').focus();       
            });
    });
    </script>
 <head>
 <body>

 <form>
     <input type="text" id="inputid">
     <button>Click Me</button>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the default behavior of a `<button>` (in the browser you are using) is submit. So, when you click the button with the form tags included, the form performs a POST.

> `submit`: Creates a submit button. This is the default value.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Add `type="button"` to the button element to stop it from POSTing the form.

To be safe, you should always specify the type of button.

Answer (score 2):

i have tested it and working perfactly...

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
              $('#inputid').focus();  
              //return false;     
            });
    });
    </script>
```

and

```
<form>
     <input type="text" id="inputid">
     <input id="button" type="button" value="Click"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use button like this:

```
 <button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#inputid').focus();
        return false;
    });
});
```

When you click on button.Form performs post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 <form action="#">
     <input type="text" id="inputid">
     <button>Click Me</button>
 </form>
```